# Merge Two DFs Without Dupes

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I am trying to merge two data frames and eliminate dupes.

Here is DF#1:

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'id':['168'],'group_id':['360002136432'],'ticket_form_id':['360000159712']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
print(df1)
```

Here is DF #2

```
data2 = {'id':['362936613051','362936613051','362936613051'],'ticket_id':['168','168','168']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
print(df2)
```

I am trying to merge, or consolidate, DF#1 and DF#2, so it looks like this.

```
id  group_id    ticket_form_id  ID
168 360002136432    360000159712    362936613051
```

It would be some kind of inner join (I think) between DF#1.id and DF#2.ticket_id, but I keep getting a bunch of dupes in the merged data frame.  How can I eliminate dupes in the merged data frame.

So, for ID = 8, I would expect to see 362563740691 and for ID = 10, I would expect to see 362563746711.

[image]

Instead, I'm seeing 362785076491 for ID = 8.

[image]

Comment: can you elaborate on the dupes? what field gets duplicates? you have duplicate rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your df2 do have a lot of duplicate values. I don't know if you need to keep redundant data, if you don't need to you can drop df2 duplicates

```
df2.drop_duplicates(inplace = True)
print(df1.merge(df2, left_on = 'id', right_on = 'ticket_id'))
```

This immediately remove the duplicate rows in the final dataframe.

Another possibility is to remove duplicated rows after the merge.

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, left_on = 'id', right_on = 'ticket_id', how = 'inner')                                                                                
df1.drop_duplicates(inplace = True)                                                                                                                        
print(df1)
```

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem.  It was those pesky dupes.  Everything is back to normal now.  Thanks for your help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all of the id/ticket_id pairs in df2 are duplicated as in the example:

```
df_new=df1.merge(df2[~df2.duplicated()==1], left_on='id', right_on='ticket_id').drop('ticket_id', axis=1)
```